# _vti_bin/listdata.svc/UserInformationList retreive null DateOfBirth in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

Im getting the User Information list with  this link:

```
https://SiteURL/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/UserInformationList
```

But the DateOfBirth return this

```
<d:DateOfBirth m:type="Edm.DateTime" m:null="true" />
```

All the user has the Date of birth in their profiles. But the list does not have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read all the users that are given direct permissions on the site from the "**Users Information List**". You can query this and retrieve only items which have content type "**Person**", and for each of them you would have to make a request to the **PeopleManager** to get their **Date of birth**.

From Below given reference URL you can find information on how to get the information for a user profile.

[Work with user profiles in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163800.aspx)

On short, you would have to make a request to

```
{SiteUrl}/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/getpropertiesfor?accountName='{AccountName}'
```

You can test the URL in the browser.

Comment: Sorry is that for Sharepoint Online?

Comment: Please check all the possibilities written here...http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html

Comment: Is this proccess slow?, because we have to retrevie first the account name of all user and the get the birth day for each user. There is a better way? or how can I do that so the performance is good

Comment: We can get the user details after getting the account name only. this is the only way we can get all details of single user & we have to do it for each user one by one. :(

Comment: And do you know what is the reason that the DateOfBirth is null in the user information list?

Comment: Sorry but i don't know the reason behind it. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40326/discussion-between-hardik-and-sebastian-a).